# Something is wrong with Qt docs

Tags: multithreading, qt

here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QThread.html on the bottom of this page is note on how one should from now on use threads in Qt. And everything would be ok if not for one little niuance, namely line no 16 in example given:

```
worker->moveToThread(thread);
```

As far as I'm concerned there is no fnc moveToThread in this class, and implementation of thereof should be explained, or am I not getting something?

Comment: In the note the Worker is defined as inheriting QOBJECT which has the moveToThread member function.

Comment: In fact, if you click on "List of all members, including inherited members" you will see it there: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread-members.html

Comment: While everyone is correct that QObject has this method, I do agree that it could do with a bit more explanation, particularly in the docs explicitly dealing with how to use threading.

Comment: @tmpearce They don't typically repeat documentation elsewhere. I would contend that if it needs to be improved anywhere, it needs to be in QObject, not in QThread's docs.

Comment: @SanJacinto I agree that they shouldn't *repeat* docs, but rather make clearer in the detailed description of how to use QThread what the purpose of this call is. That a `QThread` **is not a thread, but wraps a thread, but lives in the thread in which it is created** is an important concept that, in my experience, confuses a heck of a lot of people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`moveToThread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread) is a function in `QObject`.

Answer (score 1):

It is documented for QObject.

If you examine the inheritance relationship between worker and QObject in the example given, you will see that worker is a QObject. Knowing this, we look up QObject and sure enough, it has a [moveToThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread) member function.